# How do you make linked sliders in Qt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am trying to build a GUI that has three horizontal sliders that control some probability. Each slider can range between 0 - 1.0 but all three together must equal 1.0 at all times. Here is [a link](http://keith-wood.name/linkedSliders.html) I found that does what I want but with jQuery.

Is there any good way of doing this in Qt? PyQt more specifically but I think pseudo code will suffice.

Comment: The plugin you linked is available under the MIT and GPL licenses- you can freely use [the source](http://keith-wood.name/zip/jquery.linkedsliders.package-1.0.0.zip) for whatever purpose. If it already does what you want, why not just translate it to PyQt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.sliders = []
        slider_amount = 3
        slider_precision = 10000 # sliders work only with ints, so large ints are used and mapped to floats
        for i in range(slider_amount):
            slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
            slider.setRange(0, slider_amount*slider_precision)
            slider.setSingleStep(slider.maximum()/100.0)
            slider.setPageStep(slider.maximum()/20.0)
            slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_slider_value_changed)
            slider.float_value = (i+1)/((1+slider_amount)/2.0*slider_amount) # provide your own default values
            slider.label = QLabel()
            self.sliders.append(slider)
            layout.addWidget(slider, i, 0)
            layout.addWidget(slider.label, i, 1)
        self.update_slider_values()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def on_slider_value_changed(self, value):
        changed_slider = self.sender()
        changed_slider.float_value = float(value)/changed_slider.maximum()
        delta = sum(slider.float_value for slider in self.sliders)-1
        while abs(delta)>0.00001:
            d = len(self.sliders)-1
            for slider in self.sliders:
                if slider is changed_slider:
                    continue
                old_value = slider.float_value
                slider.float_value = min(max(0, old_value-delta/d), 1)
                delta -= old_value-slider.float_value
                d -= 1
        self.update_slider_values()

    def update_slider_values(self):
        for slider in self.sliders:
            slider_signals_blocked = slider.blockSignals(True)
            slider.setValue(round(slider.float_value*slider.maximum()))
            slider.blockSignals(slider_signals_blocked)
            slider.label.setText('{:.2f}'.format(slider.float_value))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I don't know much about PyQt, but can't you just do `self.sender().value = value` instead of iterating and checking `if item.slider is changed_slider`?

Comment: @KubaOber I store the real values separately as float numbers (sliders use ints and are not precise enough), but I think it would be better to store those values inside the existing objects... I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Ohh, I see you've succumbed to floating point magical thinking ;) A 32 bit float has less bits of manitssa than a 32 bit int does. Besides, those sliders have the actual resolution of the screen they are shown on. When you move them around, the most accurate you can get in positioning one is one pixel. You can get down to the resolution of the underlying `int` only by using arrow keys. So your approach is pretty much pointless. You should scale the sliders so that their sum equals their shared maximum value. In integers. That's the straightforward way to do it. Anything else is cargo cult.

Comment: @KubaOber You're wrong. Imagine this situation, for example: slider 1 is changed by 1, then slider 2 would be changed by 1 and slider 3 by 0. A similar error happens for any odd-number changes. Repeat this many times and you get completely wrong results. I did try to make this without floats, and something similar to my explanation happened. Also, `float` in Python actually has 64 bits... and `int` is unlimited.

Comment: That's not an error. How is that an error? The sum is still the same. Besides, good luck changing them by one with your mouse, with range set to something larger than 2x horizontal screen resolution. Unless you're expecting everyone to tap the arrow keys thousands of times. Your "error" is an entirely made up issue. Similarly, a 64 bit float has less bits of manitssa than a 64 bit integer has. And there's no such thing as an "unlimited" integer. You choose how many bits you use, but it's not unlimited. Oh well, until you get that magical computer with unlimited memory

Comment: It doesn't matter what's the implementation of integers in Python. Qt sees them the same way the C and C++ compiler will. 32 bits, usually. How Python converts multiprecision ints into platform ints I don't happen to know -- hopefully it'll saturate them and not do a module. Useless either way.

Comment: @KubaOber You still missed my main point. Even with mouse, odd-number changes would happen all the time. Anyway, why don't you make it yourself and show me?

Comment: Or rather, imagine this situation: you have a three int sliders, set for min=0 and max=2^31-1. When you store their value using 64 bit floats, you don't magically gain any more resolution than the underlying ints provide. It doesn't matter that your floating point type has 52 bits of mantissa, or that your Python multiprecision integer is unlimited when faced with unlimited amount of memory. Each slider represents exactly 2^31 values. You get exactly the same problem when using arrow keys as if each slider represented 2^4 values. Try it out for yourself. No magic there.

Comment: @BlaXpirit How do I accept it? And I meant to say thanks to you and not to Kuba for supplying the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to connect the `valueChanged` signal of the sliders to a slot you define yourself. In this slot (function) you can implement the calculation of the new values of all sliders and use the `setValue` slot to apply the new values.